# Is there a solution for this summation? a.k.a. how to proceed?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am working on a derivation to tackle a physics problem. At some point, I end up with the following infinite sum:
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac {c_1^n \Gamma(1+\frac n {c_2})  c_3^{n-1}  i^n (n+ic_3c_4)} {n!}$$

I know that all constants $c$ are real, $c_1>>1$, $c_2 > 1$, $c_3$ can be anything (real, positive or negative) and $c_4>>1$.
This heavily exceeds my math skills. In previous derivations using this sum, I ended up with a $0^n$ term somewhere, which simplified it to a form that I could understand and use.

Elements of the sum resemble standard solutions. For instance $e^{c}=\sum_0^\infty (c)^n / n!$ would make sense for a part of it, but I don't know how to account for the lower bound being 2 instead of 0, nor for the exponent being $n-1$. I figure that if the lower bound would have been 0, I would have $e^{c_1}$ for this bit and the rest would make the whole summation diverge.

Not yet fully intimidated, I figured that, since $n! = \Gamma(n+1)$, and since $n/c_2 + 1 < n + 1$ given the condition that $c_2 >1$, my intuition had hoped that the denominator grows so much faster than the numerator, that that bit would evaluate to 0, and therefore the whole thing would be 0. Unfortunately, Wolfram alpha disagrees with my intuition and gives me a result that does not please me (so, we have conclusively proven that my intuition is poor).

I think that this summation diverges, which would imply my physics model needs some work, but I am unable to write up a reason for that. Until I have that reason, I am unwilling to abandon my approach to the physics problem.

So, any suggestions on how to proceed? Thanks for your time and help.

EDIT:
I tried to simplify and it feels like progress, but again I don't know how to continue. I wrote out the first elements of the summation, and noticed I could pull out one half of the n=2 term and then separate into two sums where I pulled together elements with the same $c_3$ exponent:
$$-c_3 c_1 \Gamma(1 + \frac 2 {c_2}) + c_4\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac {i^{n-2}c_3^{n-1} c_1^{n-1} } {(n-1)!} \Gamma(1 + \frac n {c_2}) - \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac {i^{n-2}c_3^{n-1} nc_1^{n} } {(n)!} \Gamma(1 + \frac n {c_2})$$

And then I could manipulate the first of these new summations to start the summation from 0 and split that into two summations:
$$ i \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n c_3^{2n+2}c_1^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}\Gamma(1+\frac{2n+2}{c_2}) + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} c_3^{2n+3}c_1^{2n+3}}{(2n+3)!}\Gamma(1+\frac{2n+3}{c_2}) $$

If I ignore the Gamma function, these resemble the trigonometric summation expansions, and WolframAlpha can even calculate a result. Putting the Gamma term back in, I unsurprisingly "exceed computation time". I am confident I can do a similar manipulation for the other summation. Before I try that, I need to figure out whether this exercise is helpful in the first place.

So here is my explicit question:
Is there a way to account for the Gamma function term, and solve the last two summations?

Thanks for your time considering this, and for your help.

Comment: This kind of series has an expression involving hypergeometric functions. Do not expect a simple formula.

Comment: You can slightly simplify by expanding into 2 sums.